# Problems running macro in Excel 2007

Tags: excel, excel-2007, vba

I have created a macro button in Excel 2010 that works fine, and will be running it on an Excel 2007 worksheet.

My problem is this: When I run the cursor to the button (on a different computer), Excel is not recognizing it. The cursor changes from a + to the arrow, but I am not able to click or execute the button. I know the code works, and it can run the buttons command, as when I click on 'View Code' and run it from the VBA IDE and click the run button, the code works fine. Currently my macro settings are set to allow all macros. I figure I'm missing some sort of setting, but can't be sure. Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like maybe the button has no macro assigned to it? Just verify, right click the button, click "assign macro" and make sure its calling the macro you want it to.